# "ClosingActions" option for FrontEnd`AttachCell

Tags: front-end, cells, undocumented

I'm looking to find the possible values for the `ClosingActions` options `FrontEndAttachCell`. I have found `SelectionDeparture` and `ParentChanged` so far.

Moreover, is there a general method to determine the options for "undocumented" functions such as this one?

Comment: Unfortunately, the best "general method" I know of is to ask the question here and hope that someone with source code access replies. John Fultz has helped with a lot of undocumented front end functions in the past, so I think you stand a good chance.